# Converting command line arg to double fails to pass logic check in C

Tags: c, range

I am writing a C program on a Linux box.  I am trying to convert a command line argument to a double and then check if that number is larger than MAX_K. It it is larger, I want the program to exit, but it doesn't.  For example, I set MAX_K to 10^18 and then put in 1000000000000000001 as the argument and if it is larger then 1000000000000000000 then I want the program to exit, otherwise print "OK", but the program doesn't exit but prints "OK". I tried defining MAX_K as a double inside the program with the same results.  I don't understand why the program is not exiting since clearly 1000000000000000001 > 1000000000000000000.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_K 1000000000000000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

//  double MAX_K = 1000000000000000000; 

  double K;

  if (argc != 2) {
    exit(1);
  }

  K = strtod(argv[1], NULL);

  if (K > MAX_K) {
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("OK\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtod()` returns the closest `double` representable by the input string.

Inputs such as "1000000000000000000" and "1000000000000000001" will both typically convert to the same `double` given the finite precision of `double`.

So although "1000000000000000001" was entered, `K` took on a value of `1000000000000000000` and did not fail the limit test.

This is a precision issue, not a range issue.  With double values like "10000 (total 300 zeros) 000" can be entered and `strtod()` will covert to the nearest `double` that will be as expected  in the first 15 ** decimal digits.

** Per spec, `DBL_DIG` is at *least* 10

Comment: is there a way to read in a huge number such as 10^18 without it being converted to a closest double so the check would pass?

Comment: @Stochastic13 Yes, 2 options: use type `long long`, but then you re limited to integers.  Your system may support `long double` with even greater range/precision.

Comment: Without resorting to `long double`, a pedantic approach would check if `K > MAX_K`, which is certainly a failure and do extra processing when `K == MAX_K` as the input _may_ be a failure as with "1000000000000000000.0000000001", etc. Should OP provide more details of acceptable/non-acceptable values near `MAX_K` and _why_ this is important (the higher level issue), a solution could be had.

Comment: I want to check if 1 <= MAX_K <= 10^18, otherwise the program should fail. I tried changing "doubel K" to "long double K" with no luck. You explained before that stdol converts arg[1] to a closest double so I'm a little confused how changing K to long double would help. I think I misunderstood how this problem could be remedied.

Comment: @Stochastic13 I think you want to check `1 <= K <= 10^18`, not `MAX_K`.  Using `long double k` implies also using `strtold()` instead of `strtod()`.  Also better to use `#define MAX_K 1000000000000000000.0`  (Add .0).  But to the point: If user enters "1000000000000000001" or "1000000000000000000", both will convert to the `double 1000000000000000000.0`.  How then does entering "1000000000000000001" fail the _rest_ of the program?  IOWs, _why_ does the check need to fail input "1000000000000000001"?

Comment: @Stochastic13 Are only integer values allowed for `K`?  If so, convert to a `long long` and test against `#define MAX_K 1000000000000000000`.

Comment: Thank you, I converted K to long double and used strtold(), and the check passed.